# How to solve Spring boot Porm error on "Parent" tag?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I just download the application from spring initializer and imported the maven project to eclipse.

I have this error:
[image]

error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Non-resolvable parent POM for xxxxx:PasswordSafer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
- Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for xxxxxxx:PasswordSafer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

I tried to update maven --> "Update Maven Project" (with Force Update of Snapshots/Release"). but still the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

And also you can configure your setting.xml from Maven to use  this value:

```
<updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
```

See this link: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the firewall, it was blocking the update of Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but I found the best solution for it is delete .p2 file from your users folder in c drive:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McBfc.png)